# Not getting dictionary items/values for non en languages from web db

Tags: jss, dictionary

We are using Sitecore Headless. We are not getting dictionary values for non en languages from web db which is used for preview site.

We tried to get the dictionary values using Graph QL Query. We were able to get the values for en but we were not able to see the dictionary values for non en language sites.

```
Graph QL Query
-------------------------------------------

query DictionarySearch(
$rootItemId: String!
$language: String!
$templates: String!
$pageSize: Int = 100
$after: String
) {
search(
where: {
AND: [
{ name: "_path", value: $rootItemId, operator: CONTAINS }
{ name: "_language", value: $language }
{ name: "_templates", value: $templates, operator: CONTAINS }
]
}
first: $pageSize
after: $after
) {
total
pageInfo {
endCursor
hasNext
}
results {
key: field(name: "Key") {
value
}
phrase: field(name: "Phrase") {
value
}
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is because of mismatch of language codes.
In solr document, both languages exist (like de-de and de-DE) but still there is no result when we use the filter "de-de".

We need to pass the language code like de-DE if we pass the language code like de-de the dictionary values will not be retrieved.

This has been identified as a Sitecore bug with a reference number 610566 by the sitecore support team.

Answer (score 1):

GraphQL use SOLR to fetch the dictionary items. Whenever you try to fetch items using above query, call is sent to SOLR as below:

```
((_path:(*{{root_item_id}}*) AND _language:("{{language}}")) AND _templates:(*{{dictionary_template}}*))
```

In case you are trying to fetch dictionary item with canada language 'en-CA', there should be a dictionary item on SOLR with that language as shown below.

[image]

Can you check the dictionary items are there on the solr with the language you are trying to fetch items.

Hope this helps.